# Jump detection in a set of decimal numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have an array *A* of consisting of *n* decimal numbers, $A=[a_{1}, a_{2}, ..a_{n}].$
Is there any way to detect sudden jumps in the array?

For eg: A=[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5.3, 4.5, 9]
There is a jump at position 4 and a jump at position 8. Is there any algorithm to find such jumps in an array?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a numerical derivative, or adjacent difference (C++). You want to look at $B=[b_1,b_2,...,b_{n-1}]$, where $b_i=a_{i+1}-a_{i}$. If an element of $B$ exceeds a threshold of your choosing, you get a jump. How big is that threshold is not clear from your question. Does an increase from 1 to 1.1 constitute a jump?

P.S. If you use python programming language

> B=A[1:]-A[:-1]